# sql server 2008 r2 pivot

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, variable-types

Would it be possible to provide Example:

1. **Basic:** With data and columns predefined
2. **More advanced:**  With dynamic data and column predefined
3. **Expert usage of:** With dynamic data and dynamic columns

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. **Basic Examples:**

   `USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
   GO
   SELECT DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost 
   FROM Production.Product
   GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;`
2. **More Advanced Examples**

   `-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
   SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
   [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
   FROM
   (SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
   FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
   PIVOT
   (
   AVG(StandardCost)
   FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
   ) AS PivotTable;`
3. **Expert Examples:**

   `USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
   GO
   SELECT VendorID, [250] AS Emp1, [251] AS Emp2, [256] AS Emp3, [257] AS Emp4, [260] AS Emp5
   FROM 
   (SELECT PurchaseOrderID, EmployeeID, VendorID
   FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader) p
   PIVOT
   (
   COUNT (PurchaseOrderID)
   FOR EmployeeID IN
   ( [250], [251], [256], [257], [260] )
   ) AS pvt
   ORDER BY pvt.VendorID;`

Hope it helps